# Проблема в верстке

Tags: html, css

Ребят, можете разъяснить почему не работает анимация ссылок? Вроде по уму все делаю.

```css
 .header ul{
        max-width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap; 
               
        li {
            padding: 5% 2%; 
            a {
                font-size: 0.875em; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; color: aliceblue; 
            }
            a:before, a:after {
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #4bcaff;;
              }
              a:before {
                border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
                transform:  scaleX(0);
              }
              a:after {
                border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
                transform:  scaleY(0);
              }
              a:hover:before, a:hover:after {
                transform:  scale(1, 1); color: #4bcaff;
              }
            
            
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="header">
                                    
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Services</a></li>        
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Portfolio</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Features</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что в CSS вкладывать описание свойств одних элементов в описание других - это "по уму"?

Comment: У вас селекторы вложены друг в друга. Так нельзя.

Comment: Забыли скомпилировать свой SASS?

Comment: `ul` открывающийся в html потеряли

Comment: Бывает помолиться помогает

Answer (score 1):

```css
 .header ul{
        max-width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap; 
               
        li {
            padding: 5% 2%; 
            a {
                font-size: 0.875em; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; color: aliceblue; display: inline-block; position: relative;
            }
            a:before, a:after {
                content: "";
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #4bcaff;;
              }
              a:before {
                border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
                transform:  scaleX(0);
              }
              a:after {
                border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
                transform:  scaleY(0);
              }
              a:hover:before, a:hover:after {
                transform:  scale(1, 1); color: #4bcaff;
              }
            
            
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="header">
                <ul>                
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Services</a></li>        
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Portfolio</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Features</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Если вы используете SCSS, то все будет работать, хотя это очень дикий код...
Если все-таки, SCSS не юзаете, тогда так:

```css
.header ul{
    max-width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
li {
    padding: 5% 2%; 
}
a {
    font-size: 0.875em; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; color: aliceblue; 
    display: inline-block;position: relative;
}
a:before, a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4bcaff;
}
a:before {
    border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
    transform:  scaleX(0);
}
a:after {
    border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
    transform:  scaleY(0);
}
a:hover:before, a:hover:after {
    transform:  scale(1, 1); color: #4bcaff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <ul>                    
        <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Services</a></li>        
        <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Portfolio</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Features</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#" class="effect-6">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```